# Where can I find the sitemap.xml on ExpressionEngine?

Tags: add-on, google-webmaster-tools

Where can i find sitemap on ExpressionEngine v2.4.0 so i can input it on webmaster tools

If anyone knows where to find it, it would be very helpful

Many Thanks

Comment: As an aside, your version of ExpressionEngine is very out of date and you should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 20):

There is no [sitemaps.xml](http://www.sitemaps.org) out of the box in EE. You can build it using channel:entries module

[Example 1](https://github.com/colourgarden/expressionengine-google-sitemap/blob/master/googlesitemap.xml)

[Example 2](http://bluefishds.com/blog/article/expressionengine-tutorial-how-to-create-a-sitemap-for-google)

or you can use one of next add-ons:

[NSM Better Meta](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-better-meta) *(~ $40)* SEO module

[Sitemap Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sitemap-module) *($49)*

[Google Sitemap Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-sitemap-lite) *(free)*

Comment: Once you have created the XML file, where can I place it so that it properly generates the entries. If it's in the root the loops will not generate the code

Comment: I found out how to actually add it via this guide: https://greycells.net/news/adding-a-sitemap-to-your-expressionengine-site